# Object Detection - can you get mAP per class?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

In the Sagemaker UI, when you run the object detection training jobs you can see the progress of mAP over time. Is there a way to segment this value so you can track it per class?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're talking about the built-in algo, right?

Built-in algos only log well-defined metrics, which CloudWatch picks up and graphs automatically. The object detection detection only outputs the overall mAP, so no, I don't think you can't get per-class mAP during training. Interesting idea, though: any specific reason why this would be useful during training, instead of evaluating it later?

Having said that, you can definitely output and graph any kind of metric when working with *custom* algos, so that would be one way to do it. More information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/sagemaker/latest/dg/training-metrics.html

Julien (AWS)

Comment: Yeah - I'm using the built in one. I could certainly do it later. I'm finding myself writing a lot of code around the service to be able to tune it, so I was hoping there was a built-in way. 
I think I'll end up training datasets per class while I tune it so I can tune each class independently, then combine the datasets together in a model at the end.